# SendKeys not working until I close my program

Tags: vbscript

When I launch a calculator emulator, it asks for the username and password. I want to fill these in automatically. My problem is, my `SendKeys` isn't activating until I close the program. If I launch the program manually, I have to hit tab before I can type the username. I'm not sure if my `WshShell.AppActivate` is working or even needed.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim exeName 
Dim statusCode

exeName = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AX595-EmulatorV0.7\Emulator.exe"

statusCode = WshShell.Run (exeName, 1, true)

WshShell.AppActivate "Emulator"

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}" 
WshShell.SendKeys "myUser" 
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}" 
WshShell.SendKeys "myPassword" 
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of script `Run`, try `Exec`.
most simplest setup is:

```
Set objExec = WshShell.Exec(exeName)
WScript.Sleep 200
WshShell.AppActivate "Emulator"
WScript.Sleep 200
```

you may need to adjust the the first sleep delay (depends how long your app starting)